# How to integrate Terracotta ehcache with hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache, terracotta

I'm trying to connect my application to a Terracotta cluster of caches, but I'm having trouble starting my application with the configurations I've set up. I don't get any errors in the console, but if I go with debug it fails when it tries to create the CacheManager.

**The error I get is this. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.config.TerracottaConfigConfiguration**

I'm using Hibernate 4.x, Spring 4.x, Terracotta BigMemory Max 4.x.

**Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong or where I could find an up to date documentation?**

These are my configurations:

Hibernate properties:

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">ehcache-hibernate.xml</prop>
```

Ehcache-hibernate.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache name="ehcache-hibernate"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd">

<cache name="User" maxElementsInMemory="1000"
       maxElementsOnDisk="10000" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="3600"
       timeToLiveSeconds="1200" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">
    <terracotta />
</cache>

<defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="1200"
        timeToLiveSeconds="1200">
    <!--<terracotta />-->
</defaultCache>
<terracottaConfig url="localhost:9510" />
```

Maven related dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-terracotta</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.terracotta</groupId>
    <artifactId>terracotta-toolkit-1.6-runtime-ee</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.terracotta</groupId>
    <artifactId>terracotta-toolkit-runtime-ee</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm on Windows and I've started both the Terracotta server and the management console. The server shows up as active, but there are no clients connected to it.

I've tried to find examples of valid configurations using an environment similar to my own but couldn't find any.

Thank you!

Comment: We *will* need an errormessage for this.

Comment: It seems that I had a logging problem and the error didn't show up. I get this: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.config.TerracottaConfigConfiguration

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `ehcache-core` from your classpath. Add the following dependency to make it work:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
  <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The thing is that hibernate 4.x contains ehcache-core. In my case I get ehcache-core version 2.4.3, which does not contain the class net.sf.ehcache.config.TerracottaConfigConfiguration. I tried to force the application to use ehcache-core version 2.1.1 but then I get this error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.ehcache.config.TerracottaConfiguration.getNonstopConfiguration()Lnet/sf/ehcache/config/NonstopConfiguration;

Comment: Better to upgrade toterracotta-ehcache to 2.4.3. You are currently using 2.1.1 only, that is likely incompatible with your ehcache-core pulled in by hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I fear you won't get this working. I don't know of a code base (even non-official) that would support Terracotta 4.1 with Hibernate 4.x. It could well be my memory fails me here, but ...

The best you could try is using the Ehcache embedded Hibernate 2LC provider classes instead (within the `net.sf.ehcache` package), but I think these don't support the Hibernate 4.x SPI.